# Convert a 14 (fourteen) digit bigint datatype to datetime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a situation like this:
I have a 14-digit (not 13) bigint datatype column.
This needs to be converted to datetime datatype.

For example `20160418074908` (bigint) has to be converted to `2016-04-18 07:49:08.000` (datetime).

I have been going through a lot of forums, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a *string* converted to a number. Its digits have no meaning unless you treat them as *strings*. The easiest way is to convert it back to a string then parse it with `ParseExact`. You could also use modulo operations to extract individual elements. BTW a `DateTime` object takes the same space, 8 bytes

Comment: I have tried umpteen methods to convert the 14-digit number to string and then to datetime; I get this error over and over again:  'Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.'

Comment: BTW in T-SQL `datetime2(0)` takes *less* space than a bigint - only 6 bytes instead of 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to cast to `char(14)`, then use `left` to get the date part, and `right` to get the time part. The date part you can cast to datetime as is, since it's `yyyyMMdd`, but the time part you have to add `:` in the 5th and 3rd places - that's what the `stuff` does:

```
DECLARE @D as bigint = 20160418074908

SELECT CAST(LEFT(CAST(@D as char(14)), 8) AS DATETIME) +
       CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(CAST(@D as char(14)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') AS DATETIME)
```

Result:

```
2016-04-18 07:49:08
```

The advantage of this approach vs the format approach is speed.
the `Format` function is [known for poor performance](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but).

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/UUUV9439)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to *cast* them as string value for date and time separate & use `format()` function to format the *bigint* time value to string

```
select 
       cast(cast(cast(left(cast(<date> as varchar), 8) as date) as varchar) + ' ' + 
       format(cast(right(cast(<date> as varchar), 6) as int), 
                                  '##:##:##') as datetime) datetimes
from table
```

Here is short version help by  *@PanagiotisKanavos*

```
select cast(left(<date>,8) as datetime) +
       cast(format(cast(right(<date>, 6) as int),'##:##:##') as datetime) datetimes
from table
```

**Result :**

```
datetimes
2016-04-18 07:49:08.000
```

Comment: Cast the date part as `datetime` and you'll be able to just add the parts. No need to cast to date then varchar then add strings

Comment: You can shorten this to `select   cast(left(@date,8) as datetime) + cast(format(cast(right(@date , 6) as int),'##:##:##') as datetime) datetimes`. `left` and `right` implicitly convert numbers to strings. Or use `@date%1000000` to extract the time part

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help provided:

I found this one in another forum (somewhat similar to Zohar's):

declare  @DateValue varchar(50)=20160418074908

select
convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(@DateValue, 9, 0, ' '), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':')) AS ConvertedDate